# "AWS4 Signing request signature does not match" error

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I followed the steps from [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4_signing.html) for generating a canonical string and string to sign for the AWS4 SDK. And I am getting 403. This is what I get when I print the `response.text`:

```
{\"message\":\"The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.

The Canonical String for this request should have been
\\'PUT
/dev/trial

content-type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
host:myendpoint.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com
x-amz-date:20190918T002703Z

content-type;host;x-amz-date
402d04afaaf71664b4820123456789bda0df4601423fe13cc851b475798016b5\\'

The String-to-Sign should have been
\\'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
20190918T002703Z
20190918/us-west-2/execute-api/aws4_request
55f919eb5d745c06760eea01da0123456789b3b1ac1cf2bf0627701d06db0780\\'
\"}
```

I also tried to print canonical string and string-to-sign which I calculate and they are as follows:

Actual canonical request:

```
PUT
/dev/trial

content-type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
host:myendpoint.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com
x-amz-date:20190918T002703Z

content-type;host;x-amz-date
402d04afaaf71664b4820123456789bda0df4601423fe13cc851b475798016b5
```

Actual string to sign:

```
AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
20190918T002703Z
20190918/us-west-2/execute-api/aws4_request
55f919eb5d745c06760eea01da0123456789b3b1ac1cf2bf0627701d06db0780
```

To me at least, what AWS has calculated and what I am calculating are exactly the same. Then I am still getting the "signature does not match" error?

I did take a look at similar question on SO. All of them had some issue with the request, e.g. missing `\n` or different date formats. I don't believe I have those issues.

If it helps, here is how I am creating some of the components of signature:

```
canonical_request = method + '\n' + canonical_uri + '\n' + canonical_querystring + '\n' + canonical_headers + '\n' + signed_headers + '\n' + payload_hash

algorithm = 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256'
credential_scope = datestamp + '/' + region + '/' + service + '/' + 'aws4_request'
string_to_sign = algorithm + '\n' + amzdate + '\n' + credential_scope + '\n' + hashlib.sha256(
    canonical_request.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()

authorization_header = algorithm + ' ' + 'Credential=' + access_key + '/' + credential_scope + ', ' + 'SignedHeaders=' + signed_headers + ', ' + 'Signature=' + signature

headers = {'x-amz-date': amzdate, 'Authorization': authorization_header, 'host': host,
'content-type': content_type, 'x-api-key': api_key}
```

Would be happy to include more details if that helps solving this issue.

Comment: I found someone has [put this lib together: aws-request-signer](https://github.com/iksteen/aws-request-signer); haven't tried it yet; still struggling to believe this isn't included in boto somewhere.